# Is there a way to specify the data type within a style defined in a ResourceDictionary?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, resourcedictionary

Consider the following xaml definition of a `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Demo.MyControl" x:Name="self">
    <Grid Binding="{Binding ElementName=self}">
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MyBooleanProperty}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In the grid's binding above, I'm using `ElementName=self`, which directs to the control itself. This is just an example of having a binding where the data type of the binding source used by the `DataTrigger` is known at design-time. Another would be defining a style within a `DataTemplate` that has a `DataType` attribute.

I would like to extract styles defined locally to a `ResourceDictionary`, but then the data type is not available at design-time and the xaml editor cannot supply the intellisense support I have, if the style is defined as above, e.g. for the `Path` property.

Is there a way to specify the data type within a style defined in a ResourceDictionary?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of would be using the [`d:DataContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/dd490796(v=vs.100)) property that could hint in the right direction, unfortunately my VS doesn't accept it on a style.

Besides that, I don't think there is any meaningful way to solve this since a style can be applied to any element of the `TargetType` and the designer doesn't know the elements it will be applied to.